# The analogue of difference operator in Drinfeld module theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, function-fields

The theory of Drinfeld modules is, in part, inspired by the analogy between Frobenius and the operator of differentiation. My question is: what should be the analogue of a difference operator $f(x)\rightarrow f(x+1)-f(x)$?

I realize that this is somewhat imprecise but after all, there are works making the analogy above precise (see e.g. "Basic structures of function field arithmetic", section 4.14). So maybe this question is not entirely hopeless.